# Command line: Installing a font

Tags: fonts, batch-file, installation, cmd, reboot

Is there to install a font in a batch file, etc.
WITHOUT A REBOOT?

fontinst.exe doesn't work nor [this](http://www.windowsitpro.com/article/installation2/how-can-i-install-a-font-from-the-command-line-batch-file-).
these methods, would all need a reboot...

any suggestions?
maybe: NSIS, C, Batch, ...

Comment: Why doesn't fontinst work for you?  Is it possible that you need to elevate / run as admin first (and that you're hitting access denied)?  In any case, font installation should never require a reboot.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found this [article that provides a VBScript that will install a font.](http://blogs.technet.com/b/heyscriptingguy/archive/2008/04/25/how-can-i-install-fonts-using-a-script.aspx)

In Windows 7, you will have to run it from an elevated command prompt or your will get a User Access Control prompt.

```
Const FONTS = &H14&

Set objShell = CreateObject("Shell.Application")
Set objFolder = objShell.Namespace(FONTS)
objFolder.CopyHere "C:\Scripts\Myfont.ttf"
```

Answer (score -1):

I spent a lot of time to find a way for installing font without restart.
Finally, I found [ClickFont](http://www.softpedia.com/get/Others/Font-Utils/Clickfont.shtml). It's an easy and exact solution :)

> ClickFont was designed to allow quick installation of TrueType fonts
>   with just two mouse clicks. You can install multiple fonts at the same
>   time, all it takes is a right-click on a font or folder.
>
> Integrated into the Windows shell, the user has the possibility to
>   install fonts from any location. ClickFont copies the fonts, but also
>   registers them properly with a system call.

-*Softpedia's ClickFont page (as of 2016/10/04)*

See: http://www.softpedia.com/get/Others/Font-Utils/Clickfont.shtml